# Pyinstaller Unable to Convert Fully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

**Specs**

- Python Version 3.9.6 (DL'd and installed from Python's website, not
  Microsoft Store etc.)
- Windows 10

**Problem**

I've tried to package python file in cmd using *pyinstaller filename.py* and *pyinstaller --onefile Simple.py* to *.exe which does not seem to work:

> 73 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3 73 INFO: Python: 3.9.5 125 INFO: Platform:
> Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0 126 INFO: wrote
> C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe\Simple.spec 186 INFO: UPX is available.
> 188 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
> ['C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe',
> 'C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe'] 197 INFO: checking Analysis 197
> INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent 197
> INFO: Initializing module dependency graph... 200 INFO: Caching module
> graph hooks... 215 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ... 2561 INFO:
> Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from
> 'C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
> 2561 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib'
> 4598 INFO: Caching module dependency graph... 4789 INFO: running
> Analysis Analysis-00.toc Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py",
> line 35, in pywin32error
> yield   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py",
> line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
> return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes_util.py",
> line 42, in check_null
> raise make_error(function, function_name) OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 197, in *run_module_as_main
> return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py",
> line 7, in    File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py",
> line 114, in run
> run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py",
> line 65, in run_build
> PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 737, in main
> build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 684, in build
> exec(code, spec_namespace)   File "C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe\Simple.spec", line 7, in 
> a = Analysis(['Simple.py'],   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 242, in **init**
> self.**postinit**()   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py",
> line 160, in **postinit**
> self.assemble()   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 391, in assemble
> self.binaries.extend(bindepend.Dependencies([('', python, '')],   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py",
> line 224, in Dependencies
> for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py",
> line 403, in getAssemblyFiles
> for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py",
> line 354, in getAssemblies
> res = GetManifestResources(pth)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py",
> line 1016, in GetManifestResources
> return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py",
> line 170, in GetResources
> hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py",
> line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
> return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py",
> line 135, in **exit**
> self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py",
> line 37, in pywin32error
> raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror) win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920,
> 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system.')
>
> C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe>pyinstaller --onefile Simple.py 72 INFO:
> PyInstaller: 4.3 72 INFO: Python: 3.9.5 122 INFO: Platform:
> Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0 123 INFO: wrote
> C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe\Simple.spec 166 INFO: UPX is available.
> 168 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
> ['C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe',
> 'C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe'] 177 INFO: checking Analysis 177
> INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent 178
> INFO: Initializing module dependency graph... 181 INFO: Caching module
> graph hooks... 196 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ... 2579 INFO:
> Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from
> 'C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
> 2580 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib'
> 4596 INFO: Caching module dependency graph... 4777 INFO: running
> Analysis Analysis-00.toc Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py",
> line 35, in pywin32error
> yield   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py",
> line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
> return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes_util.py",
> line 42, in check_null
> raise make_error(function, function_name) OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 197, in *run_module_as_main
> return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py",
> line 7, in    File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py",
> line 114, in run
> run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py",
> line 65, in run_build
> PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 737, in main
> build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 684, in build
> exec(code, spec_namespace)   File "C:\Users\Baven\Desktop\Forexe\Simple.spec", line 7, in 
> a = Analysis(['Simple.py'],   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 242, in **init**
> self.**postinit**()   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py",
> line 160, in **postinit**
> self.assemble()   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 391, in assemble
> self.binaries.extend(bindepend.Dependencies([('', python, '')],   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py",
> line 224, in Dependencies
> for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py",
> line 403, in getAssemblyFiles
> for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py",
> line 354, in getAssemblies
> res = GetManifestResources(pth)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py",
> line 1016, in GetManifestResources
> return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py",
> line 170, in GetResources
> hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py",
> line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
> return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py",
> line 135, in **exit**
> self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py",
> line 37, in pywin32error
> raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror) win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920,
> 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system.')

What I've also done and retried to package, all of which led to the outcome above (except the UPX)

- Reinstalled
- Restarted (also updated Windows)
- Trying the conversion in virtual environment
- Fixed the UPX *(186 INFO: UPX is available.)* by downloading and placing upx.exe in the *.py folder
- Disabled (off) both (python & python3) App Installer in App execution aliases

What I find strange

- Python version shown in cmd is still 3.9.5; also 3.9.5 in IDLE which changed to 3.9.6 after rebooting my PC
- Other Python users can convert without issue
- WindowsApps folder access returned none (e.g. return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",)

When manually accessing the WindowApps folder, the notification "You don't currently have permission to access this folder." is shown. If that is the root cause, anyway to allow Python to access it?

Here's the link to the python file and what was converted: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L8vVEc4z6LYxgN6XHWwJlujVsicMgfMy/view

---

I have also tried the below code as a *.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print "Opened database successfully";
```

The below was the outcome:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py",
> line 574, in open_connection
> self.sock.connect(sockaddr) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 197, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\Users\Baven.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_*main**.py",
> line 45, in 
> cli.main()   File "c:\Users\Baven.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py",
> line 444, in main
> run()   File "c:\Users\Baven.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py",
> line 285, in run_file
> runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("**main**"))   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 268, in run_path
> return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 97, in _run_module_code
> _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\Users\Baven\Desktop\demo_mysql_test.py", line 3, in 
> mydb = mysql.connector.connect(   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector_*init**.py",
> line 273, in connect
> return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
> line 107, in **init**
> self.connect(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py",
> line 1003, in connect
> self._open_connection()   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
> line 350, in _open_connection
> self._socket.open_connection()   File "C:\Users\Baven\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py",
> line 576, in open_connection
> raise errors.InterfaceError( mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL
> server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because
> the target machine actively refused it)

They (both *pyinstaller* and *SQL*) seem to be connected to one root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue:

```
python3 -m pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```